# Error, Fault message used AP ID: APP-80W284485P519543T

Tags: paypal, sandbox

```
ERROR

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => ns3:FaultMessage
            [attributes] => Array
                (
                    [xmlns:ns3] => http://svcs.paypal.com/types/common
                    [xmlns:ns2] => http://svcs.paypal.com/types/ap
                )

            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => responseEnvelope
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => timestamp
                            [value] => 2014-02-20T10:17:27.045-08:00
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => ack
                            [value] => Failure
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => correlationId
                            [value] => 53cf284d0847f
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => build
                            [value] => 9641252
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => error
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => errorId
                            [value] => 560022
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => domain
                            [value] => PLATFORM
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => subdomain
                            [value] => Application
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => severity
                            [value] => Error
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => category
                            [value] => Application
                        )

                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => message
                            [value] => The X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID header contains an invalid value
                        )

                    [6] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => parameter
                            [value] => X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Hello,

I use the sandbox AP ID: `APP-80W284485P519543T` and I tried another one which called Client ID, which i got from the API credentials in the profile under sandbox test accounts, both didn't work and I got this error. What is the right api ID? Where can I find it? or is some other thing wrong? Looking forward for your answer. Thank you.

Regards
Jess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The APP ID : APP-80W284485P519543T is the default APP ID for the Sandbox.
But, you are making calls to live PayPAl.
The Endpoint should be something like : https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay
Also, check the if you have passed any space in your APPID.

**Client ID** is used for making REST API calls.

Comment: So where we can get the *Live* application ID? I don't seem to find it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The sandbox App ID is indeed APP-80W284485P519543T, so you're good if that's the value you're using for testing.  I guess you just need to make sure you're trimming any whitespace or any junk off the ends, and make sure your headers are setup correctly in general.

Are you working with PHP? If so, you might want to [check out my PayPal class library](http://www.angelleye.com/download-angell-eye-php-class-library-for-paypal/).  It'll make your Adaptive Payments calls very simple for you.